# Как сократить код и уточнить место?

Tags: javascript, jquery

имею

```
<div class="sl-ide">
        <div class="itek"></div>
        <div class="itek"></div>
        <div class="itek"></div>
        <div class="itek"></div>
        <div class="itek"></div>
ТАКИХ БЛОКОВ МНОГО
         <div class="itek"></div>
        <div class="itek"></div>
        <div class="itek"></div>
        <div class="itek"></div>
        <div class="itek"></div>
    </div>
```

этими скриптами группирую в разные блоки с разным количеством

вариант 1

```
let items = $(".sl-ide");
items.slice(0,5).wrapAll('<div class="red">');     
items.slice(5,8).wrapAll('<div class="red">');
items.slice(8,10).wrapAll('<div class="red">');
а таких строк много
```

мне  кажется это глупо повторять строку пять...десять  раз....

вариант 2
или вот еще вариант, но он длинее на несколько строк

```
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.itek')];
const sections = [[0, 5], [5, 8], [8, 10]];

sections.forEach((section, i) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = `div${i}`;
  document.querySelector('.sl-ide').append(div);
  div.append(...items.slice(...section));
});
```

а мне нужно задать для групп блоков одинаковую обертку(стиль)меня интересует строка   `` div.className = `div${i}`; `` , которая задает отдельный стиль для каждой группы, я пишу `` div.className = `mydivstyle`; ``  и получаю что мне нужно - одинаковый стиль для всех групп...

 НО 
может есть решение проще ---
что-то типа (ээто не работает)

```
items.slice [[0, 5], [5, 8], [8, 10]].wrapAll('<div class="mydivstyle">');
```

и чтоб это все работало в "глобальном" диве `<div class="sl-ide">`

Comment: `[0, 5], [5, 8], [8, 10]` — а у этих чисел есть какая-то закономерность? Нужно группировать именно по 5, 3, 2 шт или привели для примера?) Если нужны одинаковые группы (например по 5 шт), эту часть тоже можно выкинуть.

Comment: группировать нужно на разное количесво, в одной группе может быть пять элементов а другой десять или одинадцать....поразному вообщем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мало кода - не всегда хорошо :) Тем не менее,

`[0, 5], [5, 8], [8, 10]` сократил до → `[0, 5, 8]`, на каждой итерации можно взять текущий элемент массива и `i + 1`-й, будут получаться те же пары.

Надо заметить, что на последней итерации `i + 1`-й элемент будет `undefined`.

`.slice(8, undefined)` равнозначен `.slice(8)` и дает элементы от 8 до конца. Поэтому это не баг, а фича!)

```js
let items = $(".itek");
let cut = [0, 5, 8];

cut.forEach((point, i) => {
  items.slice(point, cut[i + 1]).wrapAll('<div class="red">')
});
```

```css
.itek {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #800;
  margin: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.red {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #c00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sl-ide">
  <div class="itek"></div>
  <div class="itek"></div>
  <div class="itek"></div>
  <div class="itek"></div>
  <div class="itek"></div>
  <div class="itek"></div>
  <div class="itek"></div>
  <div class="itek"></div>
  <div class="itek"></div>
  <div class="itek"></div>
</div>
```

Ну и, если заниматься спортивным сокращением кода...

`[0, 5, 8].map((e, i, a) => $(".itek").slice(e, a[++i]).wrapAll('<div class="red">'));`

Comment: ну я, да, согласен, *Мало кода - не всегда хорошо :)* ,  я хочу иметь оптимальное решение..., как вы считаете из всех вариантов включая ваш , что более оптимално -...или равнозначно

Comment: @Oiki +/- одинаково. Точно не узнать без измерений, а в них нет необходимости, пока это всего лишь одноразовая операция с парой сотен элементов)